# How to delete duplicates in a text file in windows

Tags: windows, duplicates

I have this type of data in a text file..

www.example.com/link1

www.example.com/link2

.
.
.
is there any way to find duplicates through command promtp?

im on windows

I checked other answers but they all are for linux.

PS: I not only need to find them but delete the duplicates. and they are thousands of URLS in the text file and obviouslyy hundreds of duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you need to find the duplicates?

If you need to find them in order to remove them, I would suggest copying the information into an excel spreadsheet. There are filtering options in excel which would help you sort out the information of your choosing.

Here is a link that could possibly help you out:

[Find duplicates in Excel](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/find-duplicates.html)

My apologies if that isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: This really solved my problem. I dumped my data into an excel file and clicked the 'Remove duplcates' button. And it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q34835472.txt"
SET "last="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('sort "%filename1%"') DO (
 IF "%%a"=="!last!" ECHO %%a
 SET "last=%%a"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q34835472.txt` containing some test data data for my testing.

This will no doubt show some sensitivity to some characters as is common with batch scripts, but given the small sample you've provided, it's unlikely to be a problem.

It works by simply sorting the file and then detecting whether each line is exactly the same as the previous line, as `sort` will group identical lines together.

---

Always best to provide the actual problem to be solved - saves wasted effort.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
DEL u:\result.txt 2>nul
ECHO START AT %time%
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q34835472.txt"
SET "filename2=%sourcedir%\q34835472.xtx"

SORT "%filename1%" /t u:\ /o "%filename2%"

SET "last="
PUSHD "U:\"
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename2%") DO (
 IF "%%a" neq "!last!" SET "last=%%a"&>>u:\result.txt ECHO %%a
)
POPD

ECHO end   AT %time%
GOTO :EOF
```

Noting that `U:` is a ramdrive.

The `sort` is performed using the fastest options available, including using the `/t` option to use the ramdrive as a temporry location rather than te default (general temporary directory %temp% which is often a conventional drive)

Using a 110Mb sourcefile containing ~5Mlines, this took just under 12 minutes on my machine.

Comment: Actually the file is of 10mb in size. and it has about 100 thousand Urls. :/

Comment: Acually i need to delete the duplicate Urls. It will tell me about thousand of them. How will I delete them?

Comment: This was taking too much time and excel did this in just a second. Thanks alot mate. :)

Comment: And i'm really really sorry. Actually i'm new to stackoverflow. Really sorry for your wasted effort. :(